# nw.js - Implementing an auto-updater in your app?

Tags: node-webkit

I'd like to implement an auto-updater into my nw.js app. The app is Windows-only. I'm aware of these 4 options, all old:

- nwjs-builder-phoenix - Archived in 2020
- nw-autoupdater - Deprecated in 2020
- nwjs-autoupdater - Not maintained since 2019
- node-webkit-updater - Deprecated in 2014

Does anyone have opinions on these, or is anyone aware of other options? Usually I'd just go with the active project, but when none are active I'm finding it difficult to evaluate which way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this has always been weak spot in the ecosystem. Primarily because the idea of an auto-updater relies heavily on the structure of your project and how you package it. There's no one general way that would work for everyone. This old GitHub post has many people supplying their own solutions:

- https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/issues/233

Your post has helped to inspire me to create a mock up for a potential library to solve this problem. You can review the current API proposal and add comments in a GitHub issue or on Gitter.

- https://github.com/nwutils/nw-splasher-auto-update
- https://app.gitter.im/#/room/#nwjs_nw.js:gitter.im

Comment: Very cool, I'll keep an eye on that project!

Comment: Of the solutions in that old GitHub post, writing a native addon for WinSparkle or Squirrel.Windows seem like viable options. I gave it a go, but a new coder that's a bit over my head so far.